# Jenkins pipeline: load properties from file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

Below pipeline codes works well:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "test_agent"
    }

    stages {
        stage("test") {

            steps {
                script {
                    sh "echo 'number=${BUILD_NUMBER}' >log"

                    if (fileExists('log')) {
                        load 'log'
                        retVal = "${number}"

                    }
                    echo "${retVal}"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

However, when I tried to put the logic of read file to a lib(named `getNumber.groovy`) and call it in pipeline, like this:

```
getNumber.groovy
def call() {
    def retVal
    if (fileExists('log')) {
        load 'log'
        retVal = "${number}"

    }
    return retVal
}
```

This is how the pipeline (test.groovy) call this lib:

```
@Library('lib') _
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "test_agent"
    }

    stages {
        stage("test") {

            steps {
                script {
                    sh "echo 'number=${BUILD_NUMBER}' >log"

                    def retVal = getNumber()

                    echo "${retVal}"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It always fail with below error:

```
        [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: number for class: getNumber
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:34)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
```

Any suggestion? How to fix it if I want to encapsulate the logic in a lib?

[Edit]
If I change this segment

```
                    load 'log'
                    retVal = "${number}"
```

to this:

```
    def matcher = readFile('log') =~ '^number=(.+)'
    retVal=matcher ? matcher[0][1] : null
```

it works. But I just curious why the previous one can't work.

Comment: Woudnt it be getNumber.call{} ?

Comment: @Curious, no need, call getNumber could invoke the function because we could find it loaded the file successfully. However, it could not recognize property "number".

Comment: How did you configure the library in Jenkins? As a global library? Maybe try to specify it (at least for testing) directly in the `@Library` annotation (`@Library('http://github.com/my/library')`).

Comment: Actually.. what does the job output say? It should start with like `Loading library ...`. If this is missing, you haven't correctly configured the library.

Comment: @StephenKing I tried there code. The shared library setup and start correctly. This question is about how  `load` step works, and why it works differently in shared library.

Comment: I didn't even notice the `load` step. This is for loading functions/libraries, not reading file contents.

Comment: I am sure the library defined and called correctly because it showed load step successfully. You could try this code. If you try the first segment of codes, it works. But if you put the logic in library and call it, the error is output as I posted. Definitely you could find the function is loaded (you could add some log info in the library part and you will find it is printed). I am really confused why the function can't work correctly when it is called as a library.

Comment: @StephenKing, it can be used to read properties, just like "Inject environment variables" in freeStyle jenkins job. Of course we can use "readFile" to get the content of files, but "load" function doesn't need to parse the file if the content organized as "<item>=<value>"

Comment: Ah, mixed it up with the `library` step.